# Обход элементов класса

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, вёрстка

Есть класс `content__article`. Как обойти в цикле все элементы этого класса (обратившись к `document.getElementsByClassName('content__article')`) и каждому из них присвоить свойству `innerHTML` некоторое значение?

Answer (score 2):

```
document.querySelectorAll('.content__article').forEach(i => i.innerHTML = 'aaa');
```

Comment: на данный момент не могу проверить, так как https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1276022/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81 не решен. (if не срабатывает, внутри которого располагается `document.querySelectorAll('.content__article').forEach(i => i.innerHTML = getItem);`.

Comment: "не могу проверить" - Вы что, мне не доверяете?

Comment: в смысле, что я проголосовать не могу пока не проверю работоспособность кода. Как только убеждусь, что код работающий, проголосую

Comment: @htmllayout, почему бы просто не убрать этот `if` для проверки? :)